# Type exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json" after update to 10.0.2

Tags: c#, nuget

I have net461 cs project built in VS2017 with `project.json` used for nuget, after update to 10.0.2 via VS nuget tool it looks like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "IppDotNetSdkForQuickBooksApiV3": "2.9.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.1",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

This gives `The type 'JsonPropertyAttribute' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'` because `IppDotNetSdkForQuickBooksApiV3` built with json.net v9.*.

I also add add.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>            
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

There is no any references in csproj except `ProjectReference` (all of them without `newtonsoft.json` dependency).

Comment: You have the package listed in both the `app.config` and `project.json` files?

Comment: I do not quite understand question. My app.config and project.json are in question.

Comment: Actually.. how did you end up with a project.json + "net461" csproj in vs 2017? VS 2017 can do csproj using `PackageReference` for both "classic" and "SDK-style" projects. There are only some exceptions that still use project.json (UWP)

Comment: You might want to check your `csproj` file manually for duplicated `<Reference>` items.

Comment: It is not dotnet core project, it is simple dll project. No `reference` other than default `<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: I upgraded to PackageReference and has same behaviour. `Add-BindingRedirect` also does nothing.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this yet? We are having the same issue in our project and it's blocking us from updating pretty much anything else.

Comment: @Aaron Not found

Comment: Found this on github. They have a workaround https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-DotNET-SDK/issues/4

Comment: ...newVersion="10.0.2.0" /> does that really work? I get FileLoadException with Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
using newVersion="10.0.0.0" /> instead like VS inserted automatically in the binding redirect of the config file.